# C# lambda behind the scenes

Tags: c#, lambda

For someone who's not experienced with using [Lambda Expresstions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx), The following code make it seems like magic:

```
int totalScore = File.ReadLines(@"c:/names.txt")
            .OrderBy(name => name)
            .Select((name, index) => {
                int score = name.AsEnumerable().Select(character => character - 96).Sum();
                score *= index + 1;
                return score;
            })
            .Sum();
```

What makes *name* refer to an element in the collection, and more interestingly, what makes *index* refer to the element's index?

Since obviously this is not a magic, besides understanding [Delegates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171.aspx) (and maybe something else?), how does Lambda Expressions work?

Answer (score 4):

No magic, all `Select` is doing is executing

```
    public static IEnumerable<TResult> Select<TSource, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, int, TResult> selector) {
        if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
        if (selector == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("selector");
        return SelectIterator<TSource, TResult>(source, selector);
    }

    static IEnumerable<TResult> SelectIterator<TSource, TResult>(IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, int, TResult> selector) {
        int index = -1;
        foreach (TSource element in source) {
            checked { index++; }
            yield return selector(element, index);
        }
    }
```

`selector` is the function you passed in, it is a `Func<TSource, int, TResult>` which means it takes two arguments, the first argument can be any type, the second argument is a `int` and the return type can be any type.

The function you are using is the anonymous function

```
(name, index) => {
            int score = name.AsEnumerable().Select(character => character - 96).Sum();
            score *= index + 1;
            return score;
        }
```

Which is the same thing as

```
private int SomeFunction(string name, int index)
{
    int score = name.AsEnumerable().Select(character => character - 96).Sum();
    score *= index + 1;
    return score;
}
```

So the `Select` passes in the `name` and `index` values and it calls your function.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't actually related to lambdas, you can just as easily pass it a method which takes a string and `int` parameter. You can write your own implementation of the select:

```
public static class TestClass
{
    public static IEnumerable<TReturnType> DoSelect<TSourceType, TReturnType>(this IEnumerable<TSourceType> source, Func<TSourceType, int, TReturnType> action)
    {
        int i = 0;
        foreach(var row in source)
            yield return action(row, i++);
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
var myStr = new List<String> { "A", "B" }.DoSelect((name, index) => {return name+index; });
myStr.Dump();
```

Result: `A0`, `B1`

Select is merely an extension method which operates on a collection. It's implementation is what determines the index, and what parameters are required to use it.

If you're not quite sure about how `yield` works, this method will produce similar results (but not lazily executed):

```
public static IEnumerable<TReturnType> DoSelect<TSourceType, TReturnType>(this IEnumerable<TSourceType> source, Func<TSourceType, int, TReturnType> action)
{
    int i = 0;
    var returnList = new List<TReturnType>();
    foreach(var row in source)
        returnList.Add(action(row, i++));

    return returnList;
}
```

You can also write your code without lambdas for the select at all:

```
private int MyFunction(string name, int index)
{
    int score = name.AsEnumerable().Select(character => character - 96).Sum();
    score *= index + 1;
    return score;
}

int totalScore = File.ReadLines(@"c:/names.txt")
        .OrderBy(name => name)
        .Select(MyFunction)
        .Sum();
```